# A construction of permuted stochastic sequences

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, permutations, random-variables, stopping-times

I am trying to understand what, probabilistically, a random permutation of a finite list of random variables is, and I tried to draw some ideas from stopped random sequences. For example, seeing a list of random variables $X=\{X_1,\ldots,X_N\}$ as measurable map from $\Omega\times[N]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (the typical approach in stochastic processes: seeing $X_n(\omega)$ as $X(\omega,n)$) works when defining the stopped sequence $X^\tau$ at random time $\tau\in[N]$, by composing the measurable map with the map which sends $\omega$ into $(\omega,\tau(\omega))$. It is easy to show that this composition, is still a measurable random variable $X_\tau=X_{\tau(\omega)}(\omega)$. I would like to do something similar by considering a randomly permuted list (say by a random permutation $\pi\in S_N$, which we can see in one-line notation as $(\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_N)$), but here I find a difficulty: I cannot start with the same map $\Omega\times[N]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as a point of view for my list, because I need a notion of order, to get to $X^\pi=\{X_{\pi_1},\ldots,X_{\pi_N}\}$. So I considered seeing an ordered list of random variables as a map from $\Omega\times S_N$ to $\mathbb{R}^N$, that is it sends $(\omega, \pi)$ into $(X_{\pi_1}(\omega),\ldots,X_{\pi_N}(\omega))$. The original list is obtained with $\pi=id$. Then I can see the randomly permuted list $X^\pi$ as a composition of this map with the map that sends $\omega$ into $(\omega,\pi(\omega))$, yielding the desired $(X_{\pi_1(\omega)}(\omega),\ldots,X_{\pi_N(\omega)}(\omega))$. My first question is: is there a more economic approach to this?
EDIT: I came to think there might actually be. By also seeing a random permutation as a vector, through its one-line notation, that is a map from $\Omega\times [N+1]$ to $[N+1]$, sending $(\omega,n)$ into $\pi_n(\omega)$, we can exploit the usual map that adds $\omega$ in the first component instead of simply using the permutation, and compose it with the standard point of view of stochastic processes earlier described: thus we define $X^\pi$ as the composition of the map sending $(\omega,n)$ into $(\omega,\pi_n(\omega))$ first and the one sending $(\omega,m)$ into $X_m(\omega)$ secondly, thus achieving $X_{\pi_n(\omega)}(\omega)$. The overall composition goes from $\Omega\times [N+1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and is therefore a random vector (it passes through $\Omega\times [N+1]$ in the middle step so it is a valid composition). It seems that these maps that doubles the $\omega$ argument (like $(\omega,\pi_n(\omega))$) are quite useful in these kinds of constructions. Do they have a name and a standard notation?

Comment: I don't see why any of these two approaches should not be economic. Context ?

Comment: I would like to then stop the randomly permuted process at a random time, so the second approach seemed more flexible as we can do a further composition with the map $(\omega,\tau(\omega))$, thus achieving a randomly stopped random order arrival of a random sequence.

Comment: In the end you get $X_{\pi_{\tau(\omega)}(\omega)}(\omega)$ measurable, in essence.

Comment: As far as I can tell, both approaches give you a random process $X_{\pi_n}$ that is indexed by $n$. The first approach looks ok to me. Why you came up with the second I have no idea.

Comment: Because the first doesn't seem to allow a random stopping time in the indices of the permutations, that is, I can compose the map that sends $\omega $ into $(\omega,\tau(\omega))$ with the one that  sends $(\omega, m)$ to $(\omega,\pi_m(\omega))$, thus matching the standard construction of a stopped process, but I cannot compose it with a map having domain $\Omega\times S_N$.

Comment: You are right in saying that both approaches give you $X_{\pi_n}$, but I think only the second gives me also $X_{\pi_{\tau}}$ for a stopping time $\tau$, as it is more economic (the construction looks at the permutation one $\pi_i$ at a time, rather than taking $\pi$ as a whole, thus making it easy to compose with the map inducing the random time). I hope it is clear (and correct).

Comment: $X_1,...,X_N$ is the original process. $\pi_1,...,\pi_N$ is another process with values in $\{0,...,N\}$ (it does not even have to be a permutation). Clearly $X_{\pi_1},...,X_{\pi_N}$ is a stochastic process that can be stopped with a stopping time having values in $\{1,...,N\}$.

Comment: Precisely, I know that informally speaking it all makes sense, but showing rigorously that what you get is a random variable, or, for example, constructing a filtration w.r.t. which the process is adapted etc requires, IMO, more detail in the construction, so I tried to look at it as a composition of measurable maps, so to have a well defined stopped process in the end.

Comment: Congrats for mentioning filtration. Hint: which one is it the stopping time must be a stopping time of ?

Comment: The $\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_N$, and that's why I devised the second approach.